# Saving files using OpenFileDialog in C #

Tags: c#

i am actually working on an application where a blob file is retrieved from my database, converted to the original file and then saved on the desktop. I would like to know if it is possible to check if a file named "xxx" already exists on the desktop and then it shall prompt me for another name. Here is my code:

```
myData.Read();

FileSize = myData.GetUInt32(myData.GetOrdinal("filesize"));
rawData = new byte[FileSize];

myData.GetBytes(myData.GetOrdinal("file"), 0, rawData, 0, (int)FileSize);

// must change paths
String desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
fs = new FileStream(@desktopPath + "\\" + myData.GetString("title") + myData.GetString("extension"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

myFilePath = desktopPath + "\\" + myData.GetString("title") +myData.GetString("extension");

fs.Write(rawData, 0, (int)FileSize);
fs.Close();
```

Comment: This code does not close your file.  Please look into the *using* keyword.

Comment: huh what do you mean, can you give me more details please, which file does not close, the filestream ?

Comment: Well it is not *guaranteed* to close the file.  Let's say that the file's path doesn't exist, or the user has no access rights to the path.  Your code will throw an Exception and never execute `fs.Close()`.  That's why you should always use the `using` statement with anything that implements `IDisposable`, such as `FileStream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `File.Exists()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see where you use `OpenFileDialog` in your code, but you should use `SaveFileDialog` class for saving files and set it's property `CheckFileExists=true`